# Cannot Get JS File to be Added in my HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, include

So I had this working perfectly fine, but now for some reason I can't get the jQuery validate plugin to load, and therefore am unable to use the `validate` method.

[image]

Clicking on this link to it opens it fine,

[image]

But it does not show in Chrome's resources tab:

[image]

Here's the code I am currently using in the `head`.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-validate.js" type="aplication/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js" type="application/x-javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImage: "css/images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            minDate: 0
        });
    });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
                     $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#mainForm").validate({
                rules: {
                  name: "required",// simple rule, converted to {required:true}
                  email: {// compound rule
                  required: true,
                  email: true
                },
                url: {
                  url: true
                },
                comment: {
                  required: true
                }
                },
                messages: {
                  comment: "Please enter a comment."
                }
              });
            });
        </script>
```

Would love any help I could get right now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'type' attribute of the script needs to be `text/javascript` - you have that one and the next as `application/x-javascript`. I suggest changing that and see if it works.

You can just remove the type attribute, actually - all browsers will assume it's `text/javascript`.

Edit: I tested and having the type be 'application/x-javascript' works - the browser runs the script. **But** notice the validation script tag has 'aplication/x-javascript'. 'application' is misspelled.